# $("#form").validate not working

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

form validation not working, form get submit without validation,

Form

```
<form name="frm-cake-pop-dtl" id="frm-cake-pop-dtl" method="post" action="">
<!-- Modal window to save -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalSaveCakePop" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Cake Pop Details</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="st_cake_name" class="col-sm-5 form-control-label"><p class="form-control-static">Cake Name</p></label>
                    <div class="col-xs-7">
                        <input type="text" value="" name="st_cake_name" id="st_cake_name" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn_Save_Details" id="btn_Save_Details"><span>Save</span></button>-->
                <input type="submit" name="btn_Save_Details" id="btn_Save_Details" value="Save">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div></form>
```

Jquery 
For not just for testing purpose place alert messages in event, no validation messages are displayed, pop up get closed on submit button click

```
var form    = $("#frm-cake-pop-dtl"),
    success = $('.alert-success', form),
    error   = $('.alert-error', form);

form.validate({
    errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
    errorClass: 'help-block help-block-error', // default input error message class
    focusInvalid: false,

    rules:{
        st_cake_name:{
            required:true
        }
    },
    messages:{
        st_cake_name:{
            required:'Cake name is required field'
        }
    },
    invalidHandler: function (event, validator){
        alert(invalidHandler);
        success1.hide();
        error1.show();
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element){
        alert(errorPlacement);
        if (element.parent(".input-group").size() > 0) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent(".input-group"));
        } else if (element.attr("data-error-container")) { 
            error.appendTo(element.attr("data-error-container"));
        } else if (element.parents('.radio-list').size() > 0) { 
            error.appendTo(element.parents('.radio-list').attr("data-error-container"));
        } else if (element.parents('.radio-inline').size() > 0) { 
            error.appendTo(element.parents('.radio-inline').attr("data-error-container"));
        } else if (element.parents('.checkbox-list').size() > 0) {
            error.appendTo(element.parents('.checkbox-list').attr("data-error-container"));
        } else if (element.parents('.checkbox-inline').size() > 0) { 
            error.appendTo(element.parents('.checkbox-inline').attr("data-error-container"));
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element); // for other inputs, just perform default behavior
        }
    },
    success:function (label){
        label.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // set success class to the control group
    },
    submitHandler: function (form){ 
        alert('IN 87');
    }
});
```

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: yes, TypeError: d is undefined. For same I check, no element id is used more than one. I have some hidden and display none fields in same form.

Comment: post the screen-shot of that error to?

Comment: no, Error in console is TypeError: d is undefined

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/cubttgow/14/

Comment: try this but not working